# Why is this <div> overlapping this <div>

Tags: html, css

How can I fix the ***div (text)*** section to not overlapping ***the black box*** when scrolled? I'm trying to do kinda a portfolio to practice and can't seem to find a fix to this problem

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
}

.overl {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 25px;
  color: yellow;
}

.space {
  position: relative;
  top: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>

<div class="overl">
  <h2>Overlapped</h2>
</div>

<div class="space">
</div>
```

Comment: Because you have used `position: fixed`

Answer (score 1):

You could give `.box` a `z-index` value higher than `0`. That way the other div (which uses `0` because that is the default) stays below it when scrolling.

**Demo:**

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overl {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 25px;
  color: yellow;
}

.space {
  position: relative;
  top: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="overl">
  <h2>Overlapped</h2>
</div>

<div class="space">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have position set to fixed: try this CSS. I changed your .box position to absolute. Is this what you want?

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}

.overl {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 25px;
  color: yellow;
}

.space {
  position: relative;
  top: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>

<div class="overl">
  <h2>Overlapped</h2>
</div>

<div class="space">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply

```
z-index: -1;
```

To the text(overl) or

```
z-index: 1;
```

To the black box(box)

Answer (score 0):

In the css file, for the box class just add z-index as 1.

```
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: black;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .overl {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 25px;
    color: yellow;
  }
  
  .space {
    position: relative;
    top: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1600px;
    height: 900px;
  }


  <!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
      
    <div class="box">

    </div>

    <div class="overl">
    <h2>Overlapped</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="space">
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the same.

[z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Refer above link to understand what is z-index.